# Sapui5 Router is not working for the second time in Master Detail App

Tags: sapui5

[image]Hello Everyone,

Im facing an issue in Routing in Master Detail Application. When im clicking on Master Record for the first time. It is redirecting to Detail View. But if i click on another record in Master View, Router is not navigating to Detail View..

Can some one help me to clear my issue ??

If you see the above pic, When i hit on First Record corresponding details are loaded in Detail View.
If i hit on second Record(highlighted in Red) my Detail page is not getting triggered.

Below is the code im trying...

## Master.controller.js

```
onItemPress: function (oEvent) {
            var contextPath = oEvent.getParameter('listItem');
            var getPath = contextPath.getBindingContext("masterModel").getPath().split("/")[1];
            sap.ui.getCore().selRecordData = contextPath.getBindingContext("masterModel").getModel().getData()[getPath];
            this._router.navTo("detail");
        },
```

## Detail Controller.js

```
onInit: function () {

            var oComponent = this.getOwnerComponent();
            this._router = oComponent.getRouter();
            this._router.getRoute("detail").attachPatternMatched(this._routePatternMatched, this);

        },

_routePatternMatched: function () {
            var detailModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            detailModel.setData(sap.ui.getCore().selRecordData);
            this.getView().setModel(detailModel, "detailModel");
        }
```

## manifest.json

```
"routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "async": true,
                "viewPath": "sap.m.serviceRequestLast.view",
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "controlId": "idSplitApp",
                "clearControlAggregation": false
            },
            "routes": [{
                    "pattern": "",
                    "name": "master",
                    "target": [
                        "detail",
                        "master"
                    ]
                }, {
                    "pattern": "detail",
                    "name": "detail",
                    "target": [
                        "master",
                        "detail"
                    ]
                }

            ],
            "targets": {
                "master": {
                    "viewName": "Master",
                    "controlAggregation": "masterPages",
                    "viewLevel": 1
                },
                "detail": {
                    "viewType": "XML",
                    "transition": "slide",
                    "clearAggregation": true,
                    "viewName": "Detail",
                    "controlAggregation": "detailPages",
                    "viewLevel": 2
                }
            }
        }
```

Can some one please help me to sort my issue..

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Is the selRecordData getting the information correctly when you click the second item ? What value is show on the debugger ?

Comment: Yes..selRecordData contain selected row details....the problem is with navigation for second time....

Comment: Aside from this totally not being the way you should do what you want to do: Is the Details _routePatternMatched hit on the second click?